# Using a custom transition layout when doing layout-to-layout navigation transitions

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, transition, uicollectionviewlayout

I am setting my `UICollectionViewController`'s `useLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions` property to 'YES' in order to perform layout to layout transitions for `-[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:]` and `popViewControllerAnimated:`. In addition, I have implemented pinch gesture-based interactive transitions.

Also, I have defined a custom `UICollectionViewTransitionLayout` that behaves differently from the original behavior of `UICollectionViewTransitionLayout`. I create an instance of my "CustomLayoutTransition" object and return it from `-[UICollectionViewDelegate collectionView:transitionLayoutForOldLayout:newLayout:]`.

I am expecting two behaviors when I do this

*`CustomLayoutTransition` is used to perform custom layout-to-layout transitions*
1) when interactive transition is triggered by pinch gesture, or
2) when I push/pop an instance of `UICollectionViewController`, e.g., by calling `[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:]`

My expectation #1 seems to be correct, but #2 isn't; It seems that when I do push/pop programmatically, the original, Apple-provided `UICollectionViewTransitionLayout` is used instead of  my custom transition layout.

Is it normal that `UICollectionViewTransitionLayout` is used instead of my custom transition layout in this circumstance?

If this is normal behavior, is there a way to use the custom transition to perform layout-to-layout transitions when programmatically pushing/popping `UICollectionViewController`?

Comment: I've just ran into this behavior and would love to see an answer. I would expect my custom transition layout to be used in both cases, but I'm also confused as to how the transitionProgress would be updated if there is no interaction by the user.

Comment: Any update about this?

Comment: Also interested in this problem. Just wanted to add that I have also tested having a single UIViewController with a single UICollectionView,  calling [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:newLayout animated:YES] and the delegate method mentioned ([UICollectionViewDelegate collectionView:transitionLayoutForOldLayout:newLayout:]) is not called either.

Comment: there has an answer for you.
link to -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22479844/how-to-interpolate-custom-uicollectionviewlayoutattributes-properties-with-uicol

Answer (score 4):

This is more a workaround rather than a proper solution, but imagine you want to change the layout by using:

```
[self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:self.finalLayout animated:YES];
```

But you want to provide your own UICollectionViewTransitionLayout, you could replace the above line by:

```
[self.collectionView startInteractiveTransitionToCollectionViewLayout:self.finalLayout completion:nil];
[self.collectionView finishInteractiveTransition];
```

and the delegate method

```
- (UICollectionViewTransitionLayout*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView transitionLayoutForOldLayout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)fromLayout newLayout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)toLayout
```

gets called as expected.

Again, I would expect the delegate method to be called without the need of triggering the transition in this odd way but it does not.