# How to interpolate custom UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes properties with UICollectionViewTransitionLayout

Tags: ios, transition, uicollectionviewlayout

I have two custom `UICollectionViewLayout` objects that use a custom `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` subclass. These custom attributes add a single property `tintAlpha` that controls the opacity of a tint overlay view attached to each collection view cell.

I now want to transition between these two layouts, using a `UICollectionViewTransitionLayout` subclass. How can I configure the transition layout subclass to interpolate the custom `tintAlpha` property on my custom layout attributes?

I could do something like this:

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     CustomLayoutAttributes *attr = [super layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

     CustomLayoutAttributes *fromAttr = (CustomLayoutAttributes *)[self.currentLayout layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     CustomLayoutAttributes *toAttr = (CustomLayoutAttributes *)[self.nextLayout layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

     CGFloat t = self.transitionProgress;
     attr.tintAlpha = (1.0f - t) * fromAttr.tintAlpha + t * toAttr.tintAlpha;

     return attr;
}
```

However this will ignore any changes applied to the attributes in `initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:` & `finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath:` in the current or next layout, and so is not actually correct. As far as I can tell, the default implementation of `UICollectionViewTransitionLayout` determines the appropriate from/to attributes and caches them, either in `prepareLayout` or `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:`. It would be so useful to have some public API on `UICollectionViewTransitionLayout` to allow us to access these from/to attributes objects, as if I try and implement my own logic on whether to use the initial/final attributes vs the standard attributes there are bound to be some discrepencies from the default implementation.

Is there a better way to interpolate these custom attributes during a layout transition?

---

**Update:**

I have just encountered an additional problem with this scenario. In the code above, when getting `fromAttr` & `toAttr` directly from the current/next layouts, the `collectionView` is `nil` for the current layout (beyond the first run loop of the transition at least). If layout depends at all on the collection view's bounds - consider a simple cover flow layout for example - then the `fromAttr` will be incorrect.

I'm really pining for a `interpolatedLayoutAttributesFromLayoutAttributes:toLayoutAttributes:progress:` on `UICollectionViewTransitionLayout` that can be overridden by subclasses.

Comment: https://github.com/wtmoose/TLLayoutTransitioning is what I've used for this. Hopefully Timothy Moose will come along and claim his bounty with a nice explanation. Otherwise, I'll work up an answer

Comment: Thanks @jrturton - I've actually looked at this project before when experiencing other issues with `UICollectionView` (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/21422584/429427), but I decided to write my own subclasses. Correct me if I'm wrong, but Timothy's code suffers from the same issues described above - that is, initial/final layout attributes are not accounted for, and his `prepareLayout` is essentially a rewrite of the interpolation `UICollectionViewTransitionLayout` does anyway. It also rather inefficiently prepares attributes every single item at each invalidation (not suitable in my case).

Comment: I've done something similar as a workaround for now (caching the from/to attributes based on the attributes returned from `[super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:]`), and this allows me to interpolate custom attributes. But I've resorted to trying to replicate the logic that decides whether to use the initial/final attributes, and that bothers me (not to mention the overhead of interpolating twice)! I've filed an enhancement request for the API to allow overriding of a method to enable custom attribute properties to be interpolated. Until then, I was hoping there might be a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Until a better solution is proposed, I have implemented the following workaround...

The default implementation calls into the current & next layouts from `[super prepareLayout]` to choose & cache the layout attributes that need to be transitioned from/to. Because we don't get access to this cache (my main gripe!), we can't use them directly during the transition. Instead, I construct my own cache of these attributes when the default implementation calls through for the interpolated layout attributes. This can only happen in `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:` (treading close to the problem of `currentLayout.collectionView == nil`), but fortunately it seems this method is first called in the same run loop as the transition starting, and before the `collectionView` property is set to `nil`. This gives an opportunity to establish our from/to layout attributes and cache them for the duration of the transition.

```
@interface CustomTransitionLayout ()
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *transitionInformation;
@end

@implementation

- (void)prepareLayout
{
    [super prepareLayout];

    if (!self.transitionInformation) {
        self.transitionInformation = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    }
}

- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Let the super implementation tell us which attributes are required.
    NSArray *defaultLayoutAttributes = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];
    NSMutableArray *layoutAttributes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[defaultLayoutAttributes count]];
    for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *defaultAttr in defaultLayoutAttributes) {
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attr = defaultAttr;
        switch (defaultAttr.representedElementCategory) {
            case UICollectionElementCategoryCell:
                attr = [self layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:defaultAttr.indexPath];
                break;
            case UICollectionElementCategorySupplementaryView:
                attr = [self layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:defaultAttr.representedElementKind atIndexPath:defaultAttr.indexPath];
                break;
            case UICollectionElementCategoryDecorationView:
                attr = [self layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKind:defaultAttr.representedElementKind atIndexPath:defaultAttr.indexPath];
                break;
        }
        [layoutAttributes addObject:attr];
    }
    return layoutAttributes;
}
```

The override of `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:` simply calls into the `layoutAttributesFor...atIndexPath:` for each element index path that `super` wants to return attributes for, which caches the from/to attributes as it goes. For example, the `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:` method looks something like this:

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPathKey = [indexPath collectionViewKey];

    NSMutableDictionary *info = self.transitionInformation[indexPathKey];
    if (!info) {
        info = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        self.transitionInformation[indexPathKey] = info;
    }

    // Logic to choose layout attributes to interpolate from.
    // (This is not exactly how the default implementation works, but a rough approximation)
    MyLayoutAttributes *fromAttributes = info[TransitionInfoFromAttributesKey];
    if (!fromAttributes) {
        MyLayoutAttributes *standardToAttributes = (MyLayoutAttributes *)[self.nextLayout layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPathKey];
        MyLayoutAttributes *initialAttributes = (MyLayoutAttributes *)[self.nextLayout initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:indexPathkey];
        if (initialAttributes && ![initialAttributes isEqual:standardToAttributes]) {
            fromAttributes = [initialAttributes copy];
        } else {
            fromAttributes = [(MyLayoutAttributes *)[self.currentLayout layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPathKey] copy];
        }
        info[TransitionInfoFromAttributesKey] = fromAttributes;
    }

    MyLayoutAttributes *toAttributes = info[TransitionInfoToAttributesKey];
    if (!toAttributes) {
        // ... similar logic as for fromAttributes ...
        info[TransitionInfoToAttributesKey] = toAttributes;
    }

    MyLayoutAttributes *attributes = [self interpolatedLayoutAttributesFromLayoutAttributes:fromAttributes
                                                                         toLayoutAttributes:toAttributes
                                                                                   progress:self.transitionProgress];
    return attributes;
}
```

Which just leaves a new method that does the actual interpolation, which is where you have to not only interpolate the custom layout attribute properties, but *reimplement* the default interpolation (`center`/`size`/`alpha`/`transform`/`transform3D`):

```
- (MyLayoutAttributes *)interpolatedLayoutAttributesFromLayoutAttributes:(MyLayoutAttributes *)fromAttributes
                                                      toLayoutAttributes:(MyLayoutAttributes *)toAttributes
                                                                progress:(CGFloat)progress
{
    MyLayoutAttributes *attributes = [fromAttributes copy];

    CGFloat t = progress;
    CGFloat f = 1.0f - t;

    // Interpolate all the default layout attributes properties.
    attributes.center = CGPointMake(f * fromAttributes.x + t * toAttributes.center.x,
                                    f * fromAttributes.y + t * toAttributes.center.y);
    // ...

    // Interpolate any custom layout attributes properties.
    attributes.customProperty = f * fromAttributes.customProperty + t * toAttributes.customProperty;
    // ...

    return attributes;
}
```

### In Summary...

So what's frustrating about this is that it's a massive amount of code (much isn't shown here for brevity), and most of it is just replicating or *trying* to replicate what the default implementation is doing anyway. This results in worse performance, and wastes development time for something that could really be **so** much simpler if `UICollectionViewTransitionLayout` exposed a single method to override, such as:

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)interpolatedLayoutAttributesFromLayoutAttributes:(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)fromAttributes
                                                                    toLayoutAttributes:(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)toAttributes
                                                                              progress:(CGFloat)progress
{
    MyLayoutAttributes *attributes = (MyLayoutAttributes *)[super interpolatedLayoutAttributesFromLayoutAttributes:fromAttributes toLayoutAttributes:toAttributes progress:progress];
    attributes.customProperty = (1.0f - progress) * fromAttributes.customProperty + progress * toAttributes.customProperty;
    return attributes;
}
```

The good thing about this workaround is that you don't have to reimplement the code that decides which layout attributes are visible at the start/end of the transition - the default implementation does that for us. Nor do we have to get the attributes for *everything* each time the layout is invalidated, and then check for items that intersect the visible rect.

Comment: I really like this idea, but I'm afraid you don't give us quite enough to go on.  Is there any way you could post an example project somewhere?  Also, what is [indexPath collectionViewKey] all about??